# How to get text from selected text to end of page

Tags: javascript, text, cursor, range, selection

I want to get all text from the selected text to end of page, that mean just the text we see on page. But when i try this, it also get text in tag 'script', 'noscript'... and other tags which not show on page:

```
function getTextFromCursor(){
    count=0;
    var allText ="";
    if(window.getSelection){
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var selRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var range = document.createRange();     
        range.setStart(selRange.startContainer, selRange.startOffset);
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var lastEl = theBody.lastElementChild;
        range.setEndAfter(lastEl);      
        allText = range.toString();
    }
    return allText;
}
```

How could i only get the text which show on page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TextRange module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) of my Rangy library could help. It allows you to work on text as the user sees it on the page, more or less. With it, your example could be achieved with

```
function getTextFromCursor() {
    var selection = rangy.getSelection();
    var selRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var range = rangy.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.body);
    range.setStart(selRange.startContainer, selRange.startOffset);
    return range.text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `range` to the `selection`, and use `selection.toString()` instead.

```
selection.addRange(range);
allText = selection.toString();
```

Comment: That will give inconsistent results between browsers: some will give the same result as calling `toString()` on the range, others will return something like the text you see on the page.